# remote execution of New-SpSite failing

Tags: powershell

I am trying to create a site collection under a web application on a remote machine using sharepoint powershell's invoke-command as below

```
$secpasswd = ConvertTo-SecureString "Dummy" -AsPlainText -Force
$cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ("super", $secpasswd)

invoke-command -computername ws-41 -scriptblock { C:\Scripts\prod\NewSpSite.ps1 } -Credential $cred
```

NewSpSite.ps1 [file on remote machine]

```
New-SPSite "https://ws-41:21000/" -OwnerAlias "super" -Name "Testsite" -Template "STS#0" -Language 1033
```

user "super" is the system admin, farm admin, db-admin still the invoke-command fails with "User cannot be found" exception

```
User cannot be found.
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (Microsoft.Share...SPCmdletNewSite:SPCmdletNewSite) [New-SPSite], SPExcepti
   on
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell.SPCmdletNewSite
```

whats  the reason?

If remotely loggin to ws-41 as "super" and run the New-SpSite.ps1 , then site collection will be created

Regards
Jeez

Answer (score 2):

It doesnt look like you specify a domain for your user. Also if your SharePoint server lives in another domain, make sure that there is trust between the domain where you execute the command and the target server domain. When using PSCredential and Get-Credential also be aware that they **do not** validate your password or user, so it will not fail if you specify a non-existing user/domain or invalid password.

Comment: Hi Anders, Thanks for the info. Both the machines are in the same domain.

Comment: Well the error indicates that it cant find the user. Did you try with domain\super ?

Comment: yes it did not work !

Comment: also in the New-SPSite command (-OwnerAlias)?

Comment: yes, still it did not work :|